# Transforming a logo into birds

Tags: modeling, animation

Any help on creating the tranformation from a logo to the breaking up into birds as seen in the url below would be appreciated.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nCnps6H6Zs&index=1&list=FL9-dceQVAeOFinL2geU4lrA

Answer (score 19):

If you pause your reference, you will notice, the text simply fades to black, while birds appear. Since this happens fast, it causes the illusion of the letters turning into birds.

Final Result.

[image]

1. Get a reference.
   [image]
2. Model a bird.
   [image]
3. Rig the bird.
   [image]
4. Animate the bird.[image]
5. Duplicate the rig and bird geometry. Create NLA strip of the action and vary them with their speed an starting frame. I now have five different birds.
   [image]
6. Group the birds: Bird_GROUP.
7. Add an emitter mesh. Add a particle system. Set it to boid. Select the Group to Render with the following settings.
    [image]
   [image]
8. Add a wind force field to give the birds some initial velocity, set a maximum for a smooth falloff. Parent the wind emitter and the particle emitter to an empty.
   [image]
9. Create the text. Add a material to it. Add a blend texture to it and make it influence the alpha. Set the Mapping input to an object you create.
   [image]
    When moving the mapping object, the text will be only partially visible.
   [image]
10. Parent the mapping object to the controler empty as well. Then animate the empty along the text. The mapping object moving along the text will make it invisible, at the same time the emitter object will spawn birds. 
    [image]
11. Add camera. Tweak the particle system. I also animated the wind influence and added a turbulence field, causing some birds to swerve and creating a more appealing pattern.
    [image]
12. Render the animation.

Comment: Great answer to a not so great question