# How can you offset animations within a particle system?

Tags: animation, particles

I am making a flock of birds using the particle system (with Boids). My base object is a single bird with a flapping animation using an armature.

When I create the particles, each bird particle is flapping in unison. Is there a way to randomly offset the pose animation so that the flock of birds is less in sync and looks more natural?

Comment: Don't think so, maybe [duplicate and group a few birds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79098/30849).

Answer (score 1):

so you can use group in render section in particle setting. you should Duplicate your object and animate them separately and group them . then in render section in particle options use group instead of object. you can add more object with more animation to the group anytime you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add rules in boid brain section. with combining rules and their evolution you can create more natural boid system

[image]

Comment: I think the void behaviour is fine. It’s the animation of the individual objects that I want to modify

Comment: @user668074 To offset the animation of each object, that is not possible with current blender particles because particles are not independent (mesh data) objects. However, you can easily achieve this with animation nodes and you can offset the animation of individual objects.